# App keeps loading pages that are not supposed to be launched on app start?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm going crazy with this.

I'm getting a very odd issue. Nothing in the log suggests anything is wrong. Quick run through of how my app works. I run the app as a new user, I see a splash screen which checks if I am logged in, as a new user I'm not, so it takes me to the login page. I log into facebook (get basic_info and birthday permissions). Then the app launches the tutorial pages viewpager (FragmentPagerActivity.class).

When the user gets to the last page there is button to say he finished the tutorials. That stores a boolean of true in SharedPrefs and takes them to a Navigation Drawer that loads google maps view.

Here is my problem. Once I get to the maps page and want to exit the app, I press the back button, app closes. If I decide to launch the app again, it will show the tutorial again **AND** launches the navigation drawer with maps view behind it!

On the splash screen I run an if statement to see if they have seen the tutorials, the SharedPrefs are returning true on that. So the if statement is running correctly. (This is what is launching the navigation drawer correctly).

If I kill the app from Android's task manager thing then launch it, it works just fine! So somewhere there is an instance of FragmentPagerActivity that is always launching on top of everything else.

Does anyone know what I can do? Sorry for the wall of text. This is how I call the FragmentPagerActivity just after logging in:

```
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FragmentPagerActivity.class);
in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(in);
finish();
```

I'm also running a service which gets the users location, in fact it's exactly this: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Could that be interfering? Please ask if you would like more code for other parts, I just can't see where FragmentPagerActivity.class is launching from. It's not called anywhere. I even commented out the one place it is called in the app on the splash screen.

I did get this in my log a few tries ago:

```
startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=package.name.here/.FragmentPagerActivity }
```

However this does not show up after I changed the context in all my Intent calls to stop `getApplicationContext()` and use `SplashScreen.this`. As a result I assume I fixed it.

Again, apologies for the wall of text, I could really appreciate someone's help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Facebook, it launches the activity everytime because it's listed in the facebook's dashboard. Changed the login page to be a fragment and it fixed the issue.